# How do I tell IntelliJ to run a query on a different database?

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea, database-connection, intellij-13

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 13.  I have a .sql file with mysql queries in it.  I have been running the queries on localhost, but now I would like to run them on my dev database server (which has the same database and tables).  I didn't want to delete the localhost connection.  However, whenever I press Ctrl-Enter on a sql query, IntelliJ (un)helpfully reopens the localhost data connection and runs it there.  How do I tell IntelliJ to associate my .sql file with the new database connection instead of the old one?  I would prefer not to delete the old connection entirely, although I know that is a workaround.

Comment: Something about creating new connection.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the best way is to go to the Database Console panel (usually on the bottom of the screen) and right click on the tab showing the server/connection title (on the same bar as the minimization icon and gear icon), close that console, and try to run the query again with Ctrl-Enter.  At this point, a popup will prompt you to choose a database connection to use.

Answer (score 1):

As of version 2017.3.1, check on your top right corner of your file's window; you can select the database from there.

[image]

Picture taken from [Jetbrain DBE-4454](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-4454) issue report.